# Displaying keywords as buttons/tags on an asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a dynamic list of keywords I want to display on a website.  It might be 1 word, it might be 10.  It varies based on how many words are associated with the ID of the user whose info is being displayed.

I want it to look something like SO has:

[image]

Any idea how I'd do that in C#/asp.net?  I looked at the Tag It jQuery widget but it's not what I'm looking for.  I basically just need the word to look like a tag, but I don't want it to *be* a tag (where you can delete it).  It's for display only, it's not meant to be interactive, although if I could get a hyperlink in there like SO has then that would be a plus.

Answer (score 0):

Add a place holder (like Panel for example) in the place where you want these to be displayed.

The create Labels / Hyperlinks controls dynamically through code, the number of dynamic label / hyperlink controls will be equal to the number of dynamic keywords that you have for a particular ID. Assign the label / hyper link text to the dynamic keyword and th enavigate URL property to be assigned in case of a Hyper Link.

> I tried posting this as a comment, but I dont have enough reputation to post a comment and hence I have posted this as an answer